# Can't view customers from backend in multi website configuration

Tags: customer, multistore, multi-website

I'm testing a multi site configuration to better understand Magento functioning.
I tried to create customers using the browser as well as a REST API call.
However, when I login in the backend, I'm not able to see the customers I've created. I know they do exist and that the registration process was succesfull, since I'm able to login in the frontend using their credentials.
The odd thing is that I can get the new customers' details using REST API calls and I see them in the new customer section in the Dashboard, but there is no sign of them under the All customers menu.
I've checked all the filter options and they are all off.

Comment: Just reindex and you will be able to see the newly created customers in the backend.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora thank you very much: you solved my issue. Feel free to write the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reindexing for customer grid has been set by Schedule, then new customers will not show immediately in the customer backend grid.

Just reindex and you will be able to see the newly created customers in the backend.

Or you can set cron for reindexing the data.